# Log executable's requests to file system (16 bit MS-DOS)

Tags: dos, 16-bit, dosbox

Here is my situation: I have an executable that upon start tries to open some file. The file is missing, so the exe fails to start. Of course there is no output on where the exe searches for given file (no path, no filename, nothing).

Now, my question is: is there any way to log all requests of an executable to file system?

To make things harder, the exe is 16-bit MS-DOS.

Comment: How do you run this app? If it runs under Windows XP, you can monitor file system access with use of System Intrnals' Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Comment: That is what I've been looking for, thank you.

Comment: ok, I'm upgrading my comment to an answer so this question won't be left marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you run this app? If it runs under Windows, you can monitor file system access with the  use of System Internals' [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)